# Laravel Sentry getUser->email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I am having trouble passing the email of a Sentry User to my db.  I can pass the id of the User successfully, but not the email.

```
public static function loggedInUser()
{
    $user = Sentry::getUser();

    if ( isset($user) )
    {
        return $user;
    }
}

public static function loggedInUserEmail()
{
    $user = Sentry::getUser(); 
            $email = $user->email;

    if ( isset($email) )
    {
        return $email;
    }
}

public function store()
{
            $id = Helpers::loggedInUser()->id;  // this works
            $email = Helpers::loggedInUserEmail()->email(); //i have tried also
            $email = Helpers::loggedInUserEmail()->email; //i have tried also
            $email = Helpers::loggedInUser()->email; //i have tried also
            $email = Helpers::loggedInUser()->email(); //i have tried also
            $input['email'] = $email;      
            $input['creator_id'] = $id;
    $this->actor->create($input);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you dump the user object?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware about Sentry, but in such case i think you should try to print object and it's methods. You will definitely get some idea to do next.

Regards